# Map list of items

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a table called openTickets. I have another table called openTicketFollowers that relates to it using a foreign key. OpenTickets does not know about openTicketFollowers but I want openTickets to have a property that is a list of its followers. Is there anyway to do this with fluent nhibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) document. The *OpenTicket* class will contain `IList` of *Followers*:

```
public class OpenTicket
{
  ...
  public virtual IList<OpenTicketFollower> Followers { get; set; }
}

public class OpenTicketFollowers
{
  public virtual OpenTicket OpenTicket { get; set; }
}
```

And this is fluent mapping of the `OpenTicketFollower`collection:

```
HasMany(x => x.Followers)
  .KeyColumn("OpenTicketId");
```

and the `OpenTicketFollower` class mapping referencing the OpenTicket

```
References(x => x.OpenTicket)
  .Column("OpenTicketId")
```